# Text is not a valid member of Frame - how do I fix that?

Tags: lua, roblox

It gives me an error when I execute it "Text is not a valid member of Frame". It's a slider script.

```
--SLIDER:

local SliderFrame = script.Parent.WalkSpeedSlider
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local WalkSpeedSlider = script.Parent.WalkSpeedSlider

local SliderFrame = WalkSpeedSlider.SliderFrame
local Slider = SliderFrame.Slider
local WalkspeedReset = SliderFrame.Reset
local WalkspeedDragging = false
local WalkSpeedDisplay = SliderFrame.WalkSpeedNum

Slider.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    WalkspeedDragging = true
end)

UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        WalkspeedDragging = false
    end
end)

UIS.InputChanged:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseMovement then
        if WalkspeedDragging == true then
            local MouseL = UIS:GetMouseLocation()
            local RelativePos = MouseL-SliderFrame.AbsolutePosition
            local percent = math.clamp(RelativePos.X/SliderFrame.AbsoluteSize.X,0,1)
            Slider.Position = UDim2.new(percent,0,0,0)
                           game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid").WalkSpeed = math.round(percent*120)
                WalkSpeedDisplay.Text = math.round(game.StarterPlayer.CharacterWalkSpeed)
        end
    end
end)
```

- I was trying to make a slider which I succeeded, but I wanted my textbox which is WalkSpeedDisplay to be able to change to the speed that I put with the slider, but WalkSpeedDisplay.Text gives me an error "Text is not a valid member of Frame" and I don't know why.

Comment: Is `SliderFrame.WalkSpeedNum` a TextLabel? The error is saying that it is a Frame

Comment: WalkSpeedNum is a textbox while SliderFrame is its parent

Answer (score 0):

Frames don't have a property known as text. If you want to add text to a frame, insert a text label in the frame and customize it to how you want.

I may be wrong about this, it would be helpful to see all the children and parents of the frame.

Also you probably shouldn't use a variable name two times, such as you did with SliderFrame.